# Top row blank in xlsx import into MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, xlsx

I have a collection of **MS-Excel** datasets in both `.xlsx` and `.csv` that get updated regularly.During an update, I save them to my C drive and convert the `.csv` files as `.xlsx`. Following this, I import them into **MS-Access** for processing.

However, I've a tedious issue, which I think is related to the *previous file format* before the conversion, but not entirely sure:

Every time I import the collection to **MS-Access**, some of the tables have an extra blank row added to the top of the table, which can interfere with some of the processes I run.

Now, it would appear that the files that were originally `.xlsx` are the ones that have this extra row, while the files that were originally `.csv` and then converted do not have this problem.

I can't give a reproducible example due to data sensitivity, but I'd like to ask if there is any general solution to this issue?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Quick and dirty solution would be to check for blank rows and delete after importing.

Comment: @Santosh That's what I currently do, but I'm looking to make incremental improvements by eliminating that step. I have several files to apply this change to.

Comment: Check if the excel file to be imported doesn't have blank rows at bottom and correctly pointing to last cell by pressing (Ctrl + End)

Comment: I usually import into an empty table and then use a series of queries to normalise the data.  Does the same as @Santosh really except the data is pushed out to multiple tables.

Comment: Yeah I'm finding that one of the files is pointing to a blank cell at the bottom of the table. Thanks @Santosh